# Rails form_for nested and associated resources with same attributes has text filled in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations

I'm creating a nested form for two associated models Playlist & Videos, they're also nested resources and I am trying to create a nested form. Each playlist has many videos and each video belongs to one playlist. They both have attributes of title and description. Going to the new_playlist_video_path leads to the title and description of the playlist being placed into the form fields for the video.

** Update **
When I visit the new_playlist_video_path(playlist) the video form renders but the controller thinks I'm in playlist#update and sends a patch request to the playlist path.

Routes

```
 resources :playlists do
    resources :videos
  end
```

My controller

```
before_action :set_playlist, only: %i[new edit update create]

 # GET /videos/new
  def new
    @video = @playlist.videos.build
  end

  private


  def set_playlist
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:playlist_id])
  end
```

Videos#new

```
<%= form_for([@video, @playlist], url: playlist_videos_path, class: "contents") do |form| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="bg-red-50 text-red-500 px-3 py-2 font-medium rounded-lg mt-3">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @video.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description,  text: nil , rows: 4, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="inline">
    <%= form.submit class: "rounded-lg py-3 px-5 bg-blue-600 text-white inline-block font-medium" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I could change the attributes on videos but that seems like too much work because I would have to re-write validations,test and a lot of HTML. How do I get my Video form to not display the title and description of the model it belongs to?

Comment: I don't really get what it you're doing here, it sounds like what you actually want here is a many to many assocations between videos and playlists and to just assocation a video and playlist instead of creating new video instances. Can you maybe try to describe what you're doing from a high level user POV instead of the nitty gritty?

Comment: Create a video that is associated with a playlist. Playlist has many videos video belongs to playlist. All set now thought thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

My form was wrong, It should have been

```
<%= form_for([@playlist, @video, ], class: "contents") do |form| %>
~~~ form contents
```

Comment: Unless this is a legacy application (pre Rails 5.1) you should be using `form_with(model: [@playlist, @video], class: "contents")`. `form_for` is a legacy method that is slated for deprechiation and removal.

Comment: Had no idea thank you!